# Are signal efficiency of selection and luminosity, nuisance parameters in a particle physics statistics treatment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In statistics used in particle physics, one often says that whatever is not the parameter of interest, is a nuisance parameter.
For example, wikipedia :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_parameter
" a nuisance parameter is any parameter which is not of immediate interest but which must be accounted for in the analysis of those parameters which are of interest."

This note describes the formalism used in particle physics :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1727.pdf

Let's consider the typical likelihood at particle physics experiments
$L=\sigma\times efficiency \times L \times Pdf_{signal} + n_b \times Pdf_{bkg}$

where $\sigma$ (which is a cross-section and has absolutely no relationship with dispersion of a gaussian) is the parameter of interest, $efficiency$ is the efficiency of signal (taken from simulation), $L$ is the luminosity, $n_b$ is the number of background.

Are signal efficiency of selection and luminosity, nuisance parameters in a particle physics statistics treatment ?
If not, why, since they seem to fullfill the criteria of the sentence "it is not a parameter of interest".

Comment: Depending on what "LHC" might mean, this seems to be a question about the experiment and not about statistics.  "Large Hadron Collider," presumably, but exactly what is the specific scientific question?  Any given experiment plausibly could address multiple different questions and the "nuisance parameters" might vary accordingly.  Perhaps, then, you should be addressing this question to [physics.se].

Comment: @whuber : by LHC, I mean indeed Large Hadron Collider. My question is about *statistics* used at LHC (profile likelihood ratio). My question is not about experiment.

Comment: "Of interest" in not a statistical issue: it's an experimental issue.  What parameters you are interested in depends on why you are running your experiment or analyzing these data.

Comment: @whuber : sorry, but "parameter of interest", called also "POI" is an official statistical word. You are not answering to my genuine question.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "of immediate interest" is slippery. One may gain or lose interest in a parameter as an experiment moves from planning, to execution, to analysis, and then maybe to providing some foundation of the next experiment.

Even in a strictly statistical setting, estimation of a population mean may require estimation of its standard deviation, whether or not one is 'immediately' interested in the SD.

> Example: The formula for a confidence interval of the mean $\mu$ of a normal
> population is $\bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$ where the sample mean $\bar X$ estimates $\mu,$ the sample variance $S$ estimates the population standard deviation $\sigma,$ and $t^*$ depends on the confidence level of the interval (perhaps 90%, 95% or 99%).

Moreover, knowing the SD in one experiment may not be of particular interest. But when planning the sample size necessary for a successful subsequent experiment (that uses the same measurement technology), having a good estimate of that SD may be crucial.

The important thing is to be able to estimate whatever needs to be estimated at the moment.

Comment: thank you, but you seem not to know the profile likelihood statistics, so you seem not to understand my question.

Comment: Mathieu, If you think someone doesn't understand your question, then please elaborate on the question to make it clearer.  Communication is a two-way process, so it's unfair and unconstructive to place the entire burden of understanding on those who are volunteering their expertise to help you.  It is particularly egregious to ask about an elementary concept like nuisance parameters and then attack your respondent (unfairly, falsely, and with no evidence) for not knowing some other elementary concept, like profile likelihood, that (at best) is only peripherally relevant.

Comment: ok, sorry that you feel bad that I say that you are not answering the question. I have added the reference  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1727.pdf used in the community of particle physics.

Comment: *immediate interest* is only to say that in some methods you can't estimate $\mu$ alone, and need to estimate both $\mu,\sigma$ simultaneously. so it's *annoying* that you have to go through trouble of estimating $\sigma$, which you don't need to get $\mu$ that you need. hence, a nuisance

Comment: Sorry, but look at my likelihood formula in my question. What is your $\sigma$ ? For me, $\sigma$ is a cross-section of a particle physics process. I'm not dealing with the spread of a distribution. See my question and the likelihood formula from particle physics topic.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian with using $\sigma$ in two different context in your question, you confused non physicists. outside particle physics, $\sigma$ means usually dispersion.

Comment: I see : this is why I put the definition of the word $\sigma$ in my question. (and unfortunately, nobody apart you understood)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make your question easy to understand to non physicists. In fact, it's pretty much incomprehensible without some experimental particle physics background. For instance, it's not clear how is the equation related to the article in your post.

Now, having said that if you are interested in the cross section $\sigma$ only, then other parameters that you estimate from MLE are nuisance parameters. The idea is that although you are only interested in $\sigma$, you need to estimate other parameters simultaneously to get the set of unknowns, then throw out all but your $\sigma$. From you comment on *efficiency*, it seems **not** be the nuisance parameter because you got it from a different experiment and don't need to estimate in MLE.

Comment: Thank you. You are the first to have understood my question. ok, so if efficiency is not a nuisance parameter, how do you explain that most teachers in particle physics say that nuisance parameters are "all what is not the parameter of interest" ? Should I understand that nuisance parameters are actually "all what *should be fitted* also but that is not the parameter of interest" ? What do you mean about efficiency : efficiency is obtained from *theory*, from Monte-Carlo simulation, not from an experiment.

Comment: the only reason I understood your question is because I was a particle physicist in my past life. now, the reason I excluded efficiency from nuisance parameters is because you didn't estimate it from the experiment in question. I assumed *simulation* meant some other work done outside your experiment, otherwise you can include it to nuisance too

Comment: so actually, efficiency (of selection) is computed from simulation, taking into account the geometry of the detector, and response of identification of the detector, but it is not based on real data.